# Deviation from means in data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a big data table called "dt", and I want to produce a data table of the same dimensions which gives the deviation from the row mean of each entry in dt.

This code works but it seems very slow to me. I hope there's a way to do it faster? Maybe I'm building my table wrong so I'm not taking advantage of the by-reference assignment. Or maybe this is as good as it gets?

(I'm a R novice so any other tips are appreciated!)

Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)

r <- 100 # of rows
c <- 100 # of columns

# build a data table with random cols 
# (maybe not the best way to build, but this isn't important)
dt <- data.table(rnorm(r))
for (i in c(1:(c-1))) {
  dt <- cbind(dt,rnorm(r))
}
colnames(dt) <- as.character(c(1:c))

devs <- copy(dt) 
means <- rowMeans(dt)

for (i in c(1:nrow(devs))) {
    devs[i, colnames(devs) := abs(dt[i,] - means[[i]])]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subtract a vector from a `data.frame` (or `data.table`), that vector will be subtracted from every column of the `data.frame` (assuming they're all numeric). Numeric functions like `abs` also work on all-numeric `data.frame`s. So, you can compute `devs` with

```
devs <- abs(dt - rowMeans(dt))
```

You don't need a loop to create `dt` either, you can use `replicate`, which replicates its second argument a number of times specified by the first argument, and arranges the results in a matrix (unless `simplify = FALSE` is given as an argument)

```
dt <- as.data.table(replicate(r, rnorm(r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its what you are looking for, but the `sweep` function will help you applying operation combining matrices and vectors (like your row means).

```
table <- matrix(rnorm(r*c), nrow=r, ncol=c) # generate random matrix
means <- apply(table, 1, mean) # compute row means
devs <- abs(sweep(table, 1, means, "-")) # compute by row the deviation from the row mean
```